# Python: Break and rejoin a list

Tags: python, list, break

Is it possible to break from a for loop of question and rejoin on the next question after running other code.

```
answer = raw_input("Did you eat in or take out: ")
answers1 = ""
if 'in' in answer:
    questions1 = ["What was the restaurant like ?  ","What was the food like ? ", "Was the waiter attentive ?"]
    for i in questions1:
        print i
        ans = raw_input("Type your answer: ")
        answers1 = answers1 +" "+ ans+"."
        call(answers1)
        if  not n_topics:
            print("No negative topic" + '\n' )
        else:
            print "negative topic" , n_topics
            break
```

So this code breaks from the for loop if there is a negative answer, but can I rejoin on the next question after dealing with the negative answer.

Comment: Just remove the `break` and the loop will continue normally after printing the negative topic

Comment: I know that, but I need to break to take the negative answer and run it through more code lower in the program, before continuing the list of questions.

Comment: You can put as much code as you want after the `else:`, provided you keep it indented like the `print` statement. Every line you put aligned with the `print` statement in the `else:` part will be executed only when `n_topics` is true

Comment: What I have the code doing is: 
Taking the negative answer and running it through another list of questions to find the cause of the problem, but then I need to return to the original list of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `continue` instead of `break`.